# Creating two elements using js and then having access to them later in another function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am building some js functionality where I will be creating 2 elements on a page

```
var createBtn = function(
  var btn = document.createElement('button')
  ...
)

var createIframe = function(
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
  ...
)
```

Pretty basic stuff, but later on I want to add an event listener  to the button that will apply a style attribute to the iframe.

Something like:

```
var displayIframe = function(
  Iframe.style['display'] = 'block'
)

button.addEventListener('click', displayIframe)
```

My question is how can I access the elements after I have created them without going through the annoyance of attaching classes to them and accessing them all over again that way. Is there someway of getting access to them in the create functions from the beginning.

Comment: You should declare the var iframe outside the function and then setting in inside. Then you can use it to change the style. Sorry i cant write the code, i am at the phone

Comment: Is that not bad practise string things like that at a global scope?

Comment: I should not be global, you should surround everything with a function so that you keep the scope inside it

Comment: Do you create both elements at the same time?

Comment: Yes I do have function wrapping around all that logic I just it was bad to do something like that, felt a lil dirty for some reason. And yes David I do create both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codes is almost correct, but some changes is needed

```
var btn, iframe;    

var createBtn = function () {
  btn = document.createElement('button');
  ...
}

var createIframe = function () {
  iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  ...
}
```

Callback function

```
var displayIframe = function(){
  iframe.style['display'] = 'block'
}
```

Attach click listener

```
btn.addEventListener('click', displayIframe);
```

Your mistakes:

1. you should declare `btn` and `iframe` as global variables to be accessible to other functions
2. function starts with `{` and ends with `}` not `(`, `)`
3. so far your codes is correct, without any error, but you won't see anything on the page because you have not attached your newly created elements to the `body`, For accomplish this try this function

---

```
function attachToBody(){
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, I dont know why you use functions to create element, but you must have your point. Try this and let me know does this work for you.

```
//this is equivalent to:  var btn = document.createElement('button');
var btn = (function(){
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  return btn;
})();

var iframe = (function{
   var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    return iframe;
})();

document.getElementById("parentId").appendChild(btn);
document.getElementById("parentId").appendChild(iframe);

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    iframe.style.display = "none";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var createBtn = function() {
  var btn = document.createElement('button')
  btn.setAttribute("id", "myButton");
  return btn;
}

var createIframe = function() {
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
  iframe.setAttribute("id", "myFrame");
  return iframe;
}

document.body.appendChild(createBtn()); // Append button to body.
document.body.appendChild(createIframe()); // Append iFrame to body.

// Get Elements by Id.
var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton"); 
var myFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");

// Add event listener.
myButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  myFrame.style.display = "none", false);
}
```